# accessing value of variable of one callback in other callback

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 2 callbacks in my program subcribing on depth and rgb image.I have detected circle and calculated its centre point from rgb data now I am trying to access the depth value of that centre point by passing the point to the second callback but when I run the code it generate "segmentation fault". Is there any solution for this??? kindly help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68365/accessing-value-of-variable-of-one-callback-in-other-callback/) by [fairy](https://answers.ros.org/users/5515/fairy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-07-23**:
you should post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd suggest you thread your system. I cannot tell if you have, for you did not paste your code.

Threading would enable you to keep the variables that you from both callbacks to be in a common [class](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/UsingClassMethodsAsCallbacks). That would get rid of your segmentation fault.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1